# Should I cut the Ora et Labora reference sheets in half?

Tags: ora-et-labora

I'm in the middle of my first game of Ora et Labora now. It comes with quick reference sheets with both Ireland and France references on it.

It seems, given my limited understanding of the game so far, that the reference sheets could be cut in half (so each piece contains only France or Ireland). Is this a good idea, or is there some reason to keep it all together?

Answer (score 3):

They can be cut in two, there's no reason to keep them as one sheet.